# pthread_mutex_lock is not instante...?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

people. I was trying to use mutex as a subtitute for atomic variables, but has the resut demonstrates,it seems that the mutex is not instante, because the "num" still have time to half change, making the if condition true.
Is this supose to work like that, or im i just doing :().
Comente please.. THankes:D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

 static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int num = 450;

void* print1 (void* e){
    while(1){
         if(num != 450 && num != 201 ){
        cout << "num-> "<<num<<endl;
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        Sleep(0.5);
        num = 450;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

}

void* print2 (void* e){
    while(1){
        if(num != 450 && num != 201 ){
        cout << "num-> "<<num<<endl;
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        Sleep(0.5);
        num = 201;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

}


int main(){

    pthread_t* threads1;
    threads1 = new pthread_t;

     pthread_t* threads2;
    threads2 = new pthread_t;
//-------------------------------------
    pthread_create(threads1,NULL,print1,(void*)NULL);
    pthread_create(threads2,NULL,print2,(void*)NULL);
    pthread_join(*threads1,(void**)NULL);
    pthread_join(*threads2,(void**)NULL);

return false;
}
```

Result:

```
num-> 450
num-> 450
num-> 450
num-> 450
...
```

I was expecting:

```
(blanck)...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not synchronize read access to the shared `num` variable with write access to the same variable.  This is clearly visible when compiling with `-fsanitize=thread`:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=3082)
  Write of size 4 at 0x0000006020d0 by thread T1 (mutexes: write M9):
    #0 print1(void*) test.cc:19 (test+0x000000400df0)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x000000024459)

  Previous read of size 4 at 0x0000006020d0 by thread T2:
    #0 print2(void*) test.cc:27 (test+0x000000400e3f)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x000000024459)
```

Read access needs some form of synchronization as well, not just write access.  Otherwise, you may not even observe updates, or see inconsistent data.  The details are a consequence of the [C++ memory model](http://svr-pes20-cppmem.cl.cam.ac.uk/cppmem/help.html).